# Restrict API access only for my authorized client applications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, oauth-2.0

My client application is a SPA built with REACT-REDUX and back-end API is nodejs with express framework.

Problem is in my client application people can access information without login 
so how to authenticate my client application without actually login to my server API.

I tried to use Auth0 but for Single page web application authentication is done only through login, there is an option for machine to machine but that is not suitable to my case because my client app is static web app no server to save client id.

i have studied few articles to get over from this most of them suggest implicit grant is suitable for my case if its true how to implement implicit grant in my client and server.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Provide the client a JWT token on successful login which he will have to use in header every time he needs to use API.

then every other request use a middle-ware to verify this token, if valid let him continue or else send auth failed in response

Comment: But in my application i cant force users to login without login i want to access API and show the info to users.

Comment: hard-code a token for the app and use it for all api call, but if someone has access to the token he can access the api or else you can dynamically create a new token when user first loads the web app and save in the cookies

Comment: that way again the API is vulnerable any one can see the token!

Comment: you can set 2 types of token one normal for all users for not important data and one generated from back-end to access restricted data